# How many users have changed their default Sort By?

Tags: support, sorting, statistics, answer-order

I am interested in knowing how many users on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) change their default sorting preferences for answers. More specifically, I want to know what those sorting preferences are and what percentage of users use each type.

> [image]

I first thought the information might be stored in a cookie. I changed my sorting preferences, cleared my cookies, and loaded a different question (to avoid being fed a cached page). My sorting preference was saved.

I checked [Data.StackExchange](http://data.stackexchange.com) but didn't see anything that looked remotely like sorting preferences.

Where is this data, and can I access it?

Comment: @iStimple is correct, it's stored server side only. Not sure if directly in the production database in a special table or Redis cache but surely it's not publicly accessible, and I suspect that even dev would have to do some manual work to get that information. (i.e. no existing interface)

Comment: I change it frequently on that site.  Honestly I wish it were saved per question, because some puzzle answers are better read by voting, others by time submission (particularly this weekend with the red vs blue competition!). But what I'm really getting at is that I suspect depending on when you sample you'll find the answer to your question varies.

Comment: strongly related (though not a duplicate): [How many votes and flags are cast by users preferring particular answer order (active / oldest / votes)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250527/165773)